# Build and Sign a 0x Erc1155 order with python

Tags: python, signature, 0x, erc-1155, eip712

I would like to use the 0x protocol to post orders through the backend of a protocol that uses 0x.

The biggest challenge here for me is to correctly sign an order with python web3 library.

```
order = { "erc1155Token": "",
        "erc1155TokenId": ,
        "erc1155TokenAmount": 1000000000000000000,
        "direction": 1,
        "erc20Token": "",
        "erc20TokenAmount": 1000000000000000000,
        "maker": "",
        "erc1155TokenProperties": [],
        "fees": [],
        "expiry":,
        "nonce":,
        "taker": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}
```

This is how the message looks like.

I do not understand if I am missing some knowledge in between.

The order to be valid needs to have a valid signature. I send the order signed to the API endpoint, and the latter should be able to match my transaction.

Is that correct? or should I verify my order on-chain executing some smart-contract functions?

Ps. I tried reverse engineering. I signed a transaction with the UI (metamask) and I tried to sign the message with different methods to get to the same signature. But I can't...

Does someone have a guide on how to make a correct order for 0x ERC1155 in python?

Thank you so much in advance